# ggplot in R: how to draw a line through corresponding dodged points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set similar to the example data in the code below. I would like to connect the two points from the same ID in the two conditions, so as to better see the individual change from one condition to the other. Each individual is only part of one "group" but has a value for each of the two conditions. Thanks for any ideas!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
ID <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5)
group <- c(20,20, 50, 50,20, 20, 80, 80, 80, 80)
condition <- c("med", "placebo","med", "placebo","med", "placebo","med", "placebo","med", "placebo")
PropYes <- c(0.13, 0.15, 0.25, 0.13, 0.54, 0.34, 0.23, 0.45, 0.142, 0.344)
exampleData <- data.frame(ID, group, condition, PropYes)
exampleData <- within(exampleData, {
  group <- as.factor(group)
  condition <- as.factor(condition)
})
#plot
p <- ggplot(exampleData, aes(x = group, y = PropYes, fill = condition)) 
p + geom_point(aes(colour = factor(condition)),position=position_dodge(width = 0.4)) + 
  theme_pander()+scale_color_ptol("condition")
```

Comment: Which points should be connected? Based on ID, you have two points within each group plotted on x axis. For instance, you have 4 points in group "20", but it's not clear to which points in group "50" or "80" they connect to.

Comment: @Roman: I would like to connect just the two points of the same ID within each group, no lines between the groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I changed by exemplar data and made the plot as suggested in the comment from tkerwin above, thank you again!

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(ggthemes) 
library(tidyr) 
library(dplyr) 
ID <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5) 
group <- c(20,20, 50, 50,20, 20, 80, 80, 80, 80) 
condition <- c("med", "placebo","med", "placebo","med", "placebo","med", "placebo","med", "placebo") 
PropYes <- c(0.13, 0.15, 0.25, 0.13, 0.54, 0.34, 0.23, 0.45, 0.142, 0.344) 
exampleData <- data.frame(ID, group, condition, PropYes) 
exampleData <- within(exampleData, {   group <- as.factor(group)   condition <- as.factor(condition) })

 plotdata <- exampleData %>%   
spread(condition, PropYes)%>%   
rename(medication = med, 
             placebo = placebo)

p <- ggplot(plotdata, aes(x = medication, y = placebo, color= group)) 
p + geom_point(size = 3) +    
    theme_tufte() +    
    geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, alpha = 0.4, linetype=2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
pd = position_dodge(width=0.4)
ggplot(exampleData, aes(x=factor(condition), y=PropYes, 
    color=factor(group), group=factor(ID))) + 
geom_point(position=pd) + geom_line(position=pd) + 
theme_pander()+scale_color_ptol("condition")
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is almost it! I am trying to switch the variable that is on the x-Axis and the one that gives different colors, because in my real data, I have a lot more participants and this solution becomes difficult to read. If I just switch the "condition" and "group" in your code, the dodge of the points happens for every participant, so that in the end I have a graph with a lot of vertical lines, one for each participant. But the lines are thought to give a general idea of the change in PropYes...

Comment: If you have a lot more participants, lines connecting two points representing the same participant will become difficult to read regardless of what you do.  You may want to rethink your visualization. About how many participants are there?

Comment: I know that it will get a bit messy anyway, so I'm looking for the least-messy way :-) At the moment there are 35, but I will have up to 80. But if let's say almost all participants have an increase from placebo to med, that should still be visible as lines that go generally up, don't you think? Especially if the alpha value of the lines are lower than 1. If on the other hand, there is no systematic increase or decrease, the graph get's very messy and that by itself tells me something too. Maybe dodging the points is not the right thing to do? I'm not very experienced in ggplot...

Comment: Consider a scatterplot with the X axis being the measured value in the placebo condition and the Y axis being the measured value in the 'med' condition.  You will have to rearrange your data slightly (probably using melt and dcast), but you will have one point per participant, which will make the graph less cluttered.

Comment: This was a good idea, in the end, I went for this solution, thanks!